# What is the meaning of "The Composition Over Inheritance Principle"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I have a few questions about the following phrase:

> The Composition Over Inheritance Principle.

1. Is **over** a preposition?
2. Is this a complete sentence?
3. I think it means one of the following.  Which is correct?

   - The composition that is better than Inheritance?
   - The composition is better than Inheritance?
4. Can the form '{noun}+{preposition}+{noun}' create a complete sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer these slightly out of the order you asked them in.  To begin, *is this quotation a complete sentence?*

> The Composition Over Inheritance Principle.

***Question 2:*** ❌ **No, it is not.**  You can tell because it does not contain a verb.  Your dictionary will tell you that "over" can be either a preposition, an adverb, an adjective, or a prefix.  None of these options are a verb.  None of the other words are verbs either.  Without a verb, this is not a sentence.

What is it?  It's a **noun phrase**.  A noun phrase is an entire phrase that acts as a single noun.  It could be the subject of a sentence, or the object, but it is not the entire sentence by itself.

Which is related another of your questions, *can the form '{noun}+{preposition}+{noun}' create a complete sentence?*  And the answer is, again:

***Question 4:*** ❌ **No, it cannot.**  Again, a complete sentence requires a verb.

Now we can get to the details.  What does it mean?  "The composition that is better than Inheritance?" or "The composition is better than Inheritance?"

***Question 3:*** ❌ **Neither option is correct**.  As you were attempting to rephrase the quoted text, you are applying "The" to "composition".  This is not correct.  "The" actually applies to "Principle".

> The Principle

Which Principle is it?

> The Principle of Composition over Inheritance

And that finally leads us to your first question.  *Is ***over*** a preposition?*

***Question 1:*** ✅ **Yes!**  Again, "over" can be either a preposition, an adverb, an adjective, or a prefix.  It's not a prefix, because it isn't part of another word.  It isn't an adverb, because there is no verb to modify.  It isn't an adjective, because that would mean we have "noun + adjective + noun" which doesn't make sense.  So it must be a preposition.

As a preposition, what does "over" mean here?  It means "is better than" or "is more important than" or "should be used instead of".

So now we have:

> The Principle that Composition is better than Inheritance.
> The Principle that Composition is more important than Inheritance.
> The Principle that Composition should be used instead of Inheritance.

Note that even these rephrasings are not complete sentences, as they do not contain a true verb.  It looks like there's a verb in each (is/used), but these verbs are merely part of the description of Principle.  The "that" makes the next several words part of the noun phrase.

---

Now.  Two of your questions are focused on it being a complete sentence or not.  You didn't provide the source where you found this noun phrase, but I'm assuming that the source used it as if it were a complete sentence-- that is, with a period at the end.  In **casual** speech and **casual** writing, noun phrases can **sometimes** be used as if they were a complete sentence.  For example:

> What day is it today?
> Wednesday.

Here, "Wednesday" is not a complete sentence.  It's just a noun!  The trick is, in casual speech, parts of the sentence can be implied, and don't need to be said.

> What day is it today?
> [It is/It's] Wednesday.

Just as "Wednesday" is a simple noun, and not a sentence, "The Composition over Inheritance Principle" is a noun phrase, and not a sentence... and yet it could be placed in a sentence by itself if the context would allow it.

I hope this helps!

Comment: The phrase is from a title of article. And, I have a confusion: it seems preposition can modify verb but noun.

Comment: I apologize, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I think preposition can also modify verb, is there anything I miss?

Comment: A preposition cannot, but "over" can sometimes be an adverb.  Adverbs modify verbs.